# How to group totals

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to group by category - But the SQL I am using is grouping them all by date.

Example:
If a user selects a date range of 01/04/17 - 20/04/17 it will show them total number found under category A

Whats actually happening:
The results are showing Category A 10 times and showing me the total number of each date rather than a complete grouped total

Hope this makes sense

```
    SELECT tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager, Count(tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager) AS CountOfCauseManager, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Account Number], tbl_ComplaintsCoded.TouchCSM, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date]
FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded
GROUP BY tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Account Number], tbl_ComplaintsCoded.TouchCSM, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date]
HAVING (((tbl_ComplaintsCoded.TouchCSM)=[Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Combo209]) AND ((tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date]) Between [Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Text204] And [Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Text206]));
```

Comment: you are grouping it by `CauseManager`, `Account Number`, `TouchCSM`, and `Mail Date`. That's why you are having multiple groups. Try to group it by `CauseManager` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get what you want:

```
SELECT tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager, Count(tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager) AS CountOfCauseManager, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Account Number], tbl_ComplaintsCoded.TouchCSM, tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date]
FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded
WHERE tbl_ComplaintsCoded.TouchCSM = [Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Combo209]
AND (tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date] BETWEEN [Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Text204] AND [Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting]![Text206])
GROUP BY tbl_ComplaintsCoded.CauseManager
HAVING CountOfCauseManager > 0;
```

Also, please read: [WHERE vs HAVING](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-where-and-having-clauses/)